# VK API уже на этапе сохранения картинки ошибка "Invalid hash"

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, api

Нужно добавлять на стену группы фотографии

```
$image_path =  dirname(__FILE__).'\img\10.jpg';
$post_data = ['file1' => new CURLFile($image_path)];

// получаем урл для загрузки
$url = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getUploadServer?album_id=".$album_id."&group_id=".$group_id."&v=".$v."&access_token=".$token);

// отправка post картинки
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$result=json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);

//// сохраняем
$imgdata=file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveWallPhoto?user_id=$id&group_id=$group_id&photo=".$result['photos_list']."&latitude=0&longitude=0&server=".$result['server']."&hash=".$result['hash']."&v=$v&access_token=$token");
```

и вот здесь ошибка "Invalid hash". До этого все идет нормально,
версия API 5.80
[image: Получаю в ответ на сохранение]

просидел уже несколько дней. может кто работал с последним АПИ удачно подскажет что не так.

P.S. может что то не указал, спрашивайте, а то з апи вк первый раз работаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для загрузки фотографий на стену нужно использовать метод [`photos.getWallUploadServer`](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getWallUploadServer), а не `photos.getUploadServer`, и после сохранить данные методом [`photos.saveWallPhoto`](https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveWallPhoto).

Comment: большое спасибо, разобрался. что значит не то делал все это время

Comment: @ОлегАвдеенко, главное быть внимательнее =)